# When run the maven build project it is showing the below error in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, alfresco-share

2018-05-23 13:28:45,098  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-26] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04232365 GetModelsDiff return status is 403
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1157)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:249)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:185)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)

Comment: Could you give us information about your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: I would recommend to run your build in plain command line and not within Eclipse...

Comment: @ yunandtidus thanks for your reply